# Restoring NuGet packages to the latest version

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

In the project I've been using some custom NuGet sources. Apparently some of them are no longer available but I do have the newer (and only newer) versions of the packages on the other (still working) server. Is there a way to restore the packages directly to the newest versions without manually replacing all the references in the .csproj and packages.config files?

I've tried running `Updade-Package -Reinstall` but I only get the following error message:

`Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution. The packages need to be restored in order to build the dependency graph. Restore the packages before performing any operations.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some packages you use (and still want to use) are no longer available, I suggest you to make a backup of them.

Find the [Nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders) on your server. On Windows this is located at

> %userprofile%.nuget\packages

Spot the packages (and version) you want to backup and copy the `.nupkg` files in their respective folders.

Then you have two choices:

1. [Create a private Nuget feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview)
2. [Create a local Nuget feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds) on your development machine

The 1st option has the advantage to be a single source that can be used on any machine you want (development machine, build server...etc) but you will have more set-up, especially for the authentication/authorization (because it's a private feed)

For the 2nd option: Simply create a `C:/Nuget` folder and put any `.nupkg` you want.
Then in Visual Studio go to:

> Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings -> Package Sources

Click on the green `+` button to add a new source, simply give it the name `Local` and browse to your `C:/Nuget` to set the source.

From now on when you want to restore your Nuget packages, Visual Studio will first look into the `nuget.org` feed and if it doesn't find the referenced packages, will then look into your Local feed and cache the installed package to the `%userprofile%.nuget\packages` of your machine.

I hope that answer to your question, I was not quite sure about what you asked and your knowledge about Nuget.

**UPDATE:**

I think I understand your question better now.

First of all, I think your misunderstand the `Update-Package -Reinstall` command. It will reinstall the packages with the SAME version as already referenced but simply reinstalling them. It's a useful command for example when you change the target framework of your project. Then you can reinstall the same versions of the packages and they will retarget this .NET Framework version.

So if a `nuget restore` isn't working then `Update-Package -Reinstall` will obviously fail too.

With Nuget, when something isn't working, you shouldn't insist but instead, find the tweak that will make it working again. I can't count how many times I went to the different caches to delete some cached packages.

I think you should try to use `nuget restore` and see what packages are causing issues, then uninstall these packages (this will just remove the reference from the `.csproj` and `packages.config` if they aren't installed in the project yet), then you can finally install the newest version of these packages.

Comment: It actually ended up with the option 2. I had to ask other employees to copy me all the packages they have in their `/packages` folder and then I could recreate the state using the local nuget feed. It still required me to use the packages to which I shouldn't have any access. The question still remains: is there a way to upgrade packages without downloading the currently specified versions of them?

Comment: @Doro I didn't have enough characters in a simple comment so I edited my answer.

Comment: @Doro just for information, yesterday I cloned one of our project that was referencing a Nuget package I actually renamed long time ago and deleted the old package from our Nuget feed. But the Nuget CLI was giving me a restore error when I was trying `Package-Uninstall`. The only way was to delete the reference from the `.csproj` and the `packages.json` files. That's a bit dumb behavior from Nuget IMO, the CLI could just delete the reference and that's it instead of returning an error but maybe there is a reason for that...

Comment: that's why I've asked this question :) there's no option to delete/update packages without restoring the versions which are specified in packages.json or .csproj. That's kinda weird. My colleges fortunately had those old packages locally so all I had to do was to copy their files to my coputer and attach local nuget repository. Worked like a charm but still - that's not what I expected from such a huge and old packages manager.

Comment: @Doro I totally agree with you